# Sometimes computer won't enter sleep state when uTorrent runs

Tags: windows-10, sleep, utorrent

Sometimes the computer ( desktop ) won't enter sleep mode when uTorrent is running ( **edit: not downloading** ). If I exit uTorrent the computer enters in sleep mode without problems.

- The **Prevent standby if there are active torrents** setting is unchecked
- The **bt.graceful shutdown** is false
- The **diskio.flush files** is false

Is there a uTorrent setting to solve this?

**Edit** ( powercfg /requests result)

```
DISPLAY: None.

SYSTEM: [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\bogdan\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe

AWAYMODE: [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\bogdan\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe

EXECUTION: None.

PERFBOOST: None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN: None.
```

Comment: BTW, are you sure you want to use utorrent? https://www.techradar.com/news/utorrent-vulnerabilities-leave-users-at-risk-of-hacking-and-snooping There are many alternatives, such as qBittorrent, that might not have that liability and that can be configured to allow sleep to interrupt downloading.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with both utorrent and qbittorrent despite every sleep and power management related setting changed according to various recommendations from all over the internet. Then only way to allow sleep seems to exit from the *torrent application after it finishes downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `powercfg /requests` in a command prompt with Administrative privilege to query software and drivers' requests that may prevent your computer from entering sleep. You can
try adjusting related settings or ending relevant processes (be careful for that!), or (if the problem still exists) attach the list in the question so we have more information for it.

Comment: I attached the result list